# hibernate communication link failure

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I am getting this error when connecting to the mysql database through Spring hibernate in ubunto 14.4. This is working on My local environment perfectly.

```
Nov 09, 2014 2:37:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
Nov 09, 2014 2:37:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Communications link failure
```

can anyone help me out to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336861/spring-boot-communications-link-failure-after-some-hours-of-inactivity-with-hib). I was with **Spring Boot** and these configurations in the `application.properties` file resolved the problem:

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 3600000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

Hope can be helpful for someone else.

See here for more info: http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/07/09/spring-boot-communications-link-failure-with-mysql-and-hibernate/