# Spring Boot: Communications link failure after some hours of inactivity with Hibernate, JDBC and MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-boot

I get this error if my Spring Boot application is inactive for several hours (e.g. during the night):

```
2015-05-19 09:16:32.666  WARN 20582 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2015-05-19 09:16:32.668 ERROR 20582 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 29.792.613 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 6 milliseconds ago.
```

Trying to solving this problem I read that **MySQL** have a parameter named `wait_timeout` setted by default to 8 hours (28800 seconds) and after this time all my inactive connections are closed, so my Spring Boot application stop to works...

My questions are:

- How can I avoid this problem?
- Should I increase the value for such parameter?
- Are there any drawbacks increasing such value? (It could always be a value reached by my application if it is inactive so long.. :/ )
- Is not there another solution using **Spring Boot** (like a polling or something like that)?

---

**EDIT**

There are other similar/useful questions here:

- [Hibernate Communications Link Failure in Hibernate Based Java Servlet application powered by MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912322/hibernate-communications-link-failure-in-hibernate-based-java-servlet-applicatio)
- [Spring is losing connection to the DB and does not recover or reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609565/spring-is-losing-connection-to-the-db-and-does-not-recover-or-reconnect)
- [WARN SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01- SqlExceptionHelper:144 - Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752667/warn-sqlexceptionhelper143-sql-error-0-sqlstate-08s01-sqlexceptionhelper)
- [SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01 Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459990/sql-error-0-sqlstate-08s01-communications-link-failure)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally
- [Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

From references above I can conclude that one solution is to add **C3p0** as additional library and properly configure it to avoid the communication link error..

Is it the only solution I have? Isn't there a solution more "integrated" with Spring/Spring Boot (i.e. without adding an external library)?

Comment: You should read past the C3P0 comments. There are MySQL tweaks and tweaks to your connection URL (validation query and auto-reconnect are the most important).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for your suggestions. Reading here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667289/why-does-autoreconnect-true-not-seem-to-work it seems that setting `autoReconnect`in the connection string is not reccomended.. So I'm going to try with some options for my datasource: `testWhileIdle`, `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` and `validationQuery`. However I'm still waiting for some good and "definitive" answer :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved the problem as described here:
http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/07/09/spring-boot-communications-link-failure-with-mysql-and-hibernate/ , adding these configurations in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```